# Random string from 4 to 12 characters using just one character

Tags: php

I need to generate something like this using PHP:

```
******
*********
****
***********
******
********
*******
*********
*******
**********
********
******
********
```

using PHP.

So, if i.e. I have this code so far:

```
<?php 

$character = "*"; //character that will be used in generated strings

$min = "4"; //minimum characters for a generated string

$max = "12"; //maximum characters for a generated string

?>
```

What is the efficient way to write the next part of the code for rand() and echo of the string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat) in conjunction with [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) (or plain old [`rand()`](http://php.net/rand)) using those variables.

```
echo str_repeat($character, mt_rand($min, $max));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$character = "*"; //character that will be used in generated strings
$min = "4"; //minimum characters for a generated string
$max = "12"; //maximum characters for a generated string

echo str_repeat($character, mt_rand($min, $max);
?>
```